# OS X process with open serial port can't be killed with Force Quit or sudo kill -9

Tags: python, macos, process, serial-port, kill

I have a Python process which opens up a USB serial port connection to an Arduino using pyserial.   It usually works great.  Sometimes it hangs without returning, and in that state I am unable to kill the process.  Usually the Force Quit dialog or looking up the process ID and issuing "sudo kill -9 " will do the trick, but this process refuses to die.   The only solution I have to far is to reboot.

Here is what I'm trying: kill process, which returns 0 (success).  But ps shows it is still alive:

```
$ sudo kill -9 4224
$ echo $?
0
$ ps auxw|grep 4224
velotron         4224   0.0  0.1  2463884   5012   ??  U     4:15PM   0:00.05 /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python serialtest.py
```

I'm sure I have bugs to fix in my code, but is there any way to kill this process to release its' control of the serial port?   Rebooting is getting old.

Comment: On a hunch: What type of serial device are you using? This may be a bug in the driver.

Comment: I'm opening up the port /dev/tty.usbmodemfd141, which connects to the Arduino over USB.

Comment: Do you know what type of USB-to-serial bridge it's using? FTDI, perhaps?

Comment: It's the Arduino Uno, which according to the docs doesn't use FTDI but instead has an [http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardUno#.UxrRYuewKIU] Atmega16U2 Atmega8U2 up to version R2) programmed as a USB-to-serial converter].

Comment: Did you ever learn how to clean this up? I'm experiencing similar locks.

Comment: I haven't seen this problem in a while. Somewhere along the way, I upgraded pyserial to 3.2.1. That might have been it but I'm not sure.